# Translation of 何かにつけて

Tags: grammar

> 父は何か**につけて**、若いころ外国で過ごした思い出を語る。

Is this sentence best translated as "My father would sometimes talk about his memories as a young man travelling abroad".

If yes, what is the difference between 何かにつけて and something simpler like 時々、時に etc.?

Answer (score 7):

> Is this sentence best translated as "My father would sometimes talk about his memories as a young man travelling abroad."?

I would definitely have to say **NO**.  The word choice of "sometimes" does not reflect the meaning and nuance of 「何かにつけて」 at all.

That translation basically says "***Someone does something at a certain frequency***."  It sounds very neutral and it is that neutrality that is the problem here because the expression 「何かにつけて」 is ***not*** neutral.  It is indeed fairly ***negative***.

「何かにつけて～～する」 means "***to never miss a chance (to do something)***", "***to take every opportunity (to do something)***", etc.

This father speaks about his memories more often than his family want to listen.  That is the nuance of the original Japanese sentence and the expression 「何かにつけて」
.

Answer (score 2):

According to weblio:

> 機会があるたびに、または何事にも関連付けて、いつもそれを行うさま。「何かと」。

時々 or 時に would just imply "from time to time", "occasionally", "sometimes", etc. showing *how often* he talked about his experiences.

Using「何かに付けて」 shows that "whenever he had an opportunity" he would talk about the subject, and he may even try to *make* an opportunity to talk about it from an unrelated conversation.

http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91%E3%81%A6